# How to check if HTML5 Canvas blend modes are supported in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to programatically find if my browser supports HTML5 blend modes ( http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode) ?

My code structure is as below

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "soft-light";
    if (context.globalCompositeOperation){
      //browser supports
      alert('true');
    }
    else {
      // browser doesn't support
      alert('false');
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work correct. It alerts 'true' even in IE. (http://caniuse.com/#search=blend says blend mode is not supported in IE though)

Comment: css `mix-blend-mode` is *a little bit* different than [`context2d.globalCompositeOperation`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#canvascompositingandblending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = blendMode;
if (context.globalCompositeOperation !== blendMode){
     // not supported mode
}
```

Comment: That will work in most cases, except in Safari, where some blend modes ("hue", "saturation", "color", "luminosity") will be accepted but not actually supported. [In this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33956608/3702797) you can find a way to really test every globalCompositeOperation mode.